# Applications of Jack polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I developed four libraries (Julia, R, Python, Haskell) for the computation of Jack polynomials. I developed them for fun because I found this was programmatically interesting. But now I'd like them to be useful. The zonal polynomials are particular cases ($\alpha=2$) of Jack polynomials (up to a renormalization), and they have some applications in multivariate statistics. They also appear in the "usual" hypergeometric functions of a matrix argument. The Schur polynomials are particular cases ($\alpha=1$) of Jack polynomials and they have some applications in combinatorics. I'm wondering whether there are some applications of Jack polynomials other than zonal or Schur polynomials. Nothing is said about the applications on Wikipedia, and I haven't be able to find this information elsewhere. Would you know such an application?

Comment: There are really intriguing connections between Jack polynomials and the enumeration of certain kinds of maps (i.e., planar graphs). Some of these connections are only conjectural at the moment. At any rate, I'm not sure if this qualifies as an "application."

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that Jack polynomials are a special case (or limiting case, rather) of Macdonald polynomials. Many of the general features of Macdonald polynomials are visible already at the level of Jack polynomials.